# How to upload mapping.txt to PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

I want to upload mapping.txt to Google Playstore to get de-obfuscated crash reports. At upload of a new APK nobody ask for that.
How can I upload mapping text?

Comment: upvoted. fyi to downvoter; the initial upload of an app indeed does not prompt for the mapping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your playstore console account select your app -> crashes and ANRs -> Deobfuscation Files   there you can upload your mapping.txt for specific version.

Comment: Not here anymore.  So most popular answer

Answer (score 52):

For the new PlayStore UI :

- Go to Release/"App bundle explorer"
- Select the right artifact in the top right corner
- Open Downloads tab
- Scroll to the Assests section
- Next to the "ReTrace mapping file" there should be an upload Button

Comment: I don't believe I would have ever found it by myself - thank you so much! The "Search Play Console" was useless too - search for mapping / obsfucat / decode / proguard turned up nothing (and I thought Google was good with search!). This location is so obscure, with no hints. Bonus is though, now you can upload mapping.txt without needing to wait for a live crash (as it used to be). Thanks for this :)

Comment: User friendly UI by Google :)

Comment: I'm getting "The file you've uploaded is empty. Try uploading a different file."... I've set `minifyEnabled: true` in my `build.gradle`.

Comment: THis should be the answer

Answer (score 25):

I have done this following these steps....

First go to **Releases overview** page

[image]

Then click here

[image]

Then click on the three dot icon

[image]

Then click on the **Upload ReTrace mapping file** option and upload the mapping file there

[image]

You can find the mapping file in the ***app/build/outputs/mapping/release*** folder

Answer (score 13):

Debugging symbols can be uploaded, but how to do it changes. The doc is here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281?hl=en

Playstore has changed again as of 2017-06-02Fri. Now go to app / Android Vitals / Deobfuscation files to upload a mapping.txt.

[image]

Comment: Can't find Android Vitals, July 2018.  Any thoughts on how to upload?

Comment: @JeffPadgett I see it on my console right under "Statistics" (august 2018). Still don't see it?

Comment: Yeah this has moved to another section, thanks google

Answer (score 1):

Release
-> Production
-> Releases
-> select the version you want to upload the mapping file  and click "View release details"

-> App bundles and APKs
-> New app bundles and APKs
click "⋮"
where you can find upload Retrace mapping file